# How to fix fatal error 1104 with Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools when installing a python package with pip?

Tags: python, visual-studio, pip, netcdf4

I'm trying to install the package `netcdf4` in my Python project using `pip` but for some reason the `cftime` dependency cannot be installed due to issues with PEP517. The full error message is shown below:

```
(Summer research) E:\Summer research\pythonProject>pip install "E:\Summer research\pythonProject\netCDF4-1.5.6-cp38-cp38-win32.whl"
Processing e:\summer research\pythonproject\netcdf4-1.5.6-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9 in e:\summer research\lib\site-packages (from netCDF4==1.5.6) (1.20.2)
Collecting cftime
  Using cached cftime-1.5.0.tar.gz (44 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: cftime
  Building wheel for cftime (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'e:\summer research\scripts\python.exe' 'e:\summer research\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\
Users\URVIVE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo004nhne'
       cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_8rj6d0c\cftime_a623918a367c408c9828a26ecbee7bde
  Complete output (25 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\cftime
  copying src\cftime\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cftime
  running build_ext
  building 'cftime._cftime' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\Users
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\Users\User
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\Users\User\AppData
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\Users\User\AppData\Local
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_8rj6d0c
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_8rj6d0c\cftime_a623918a367c408c9828a26ecbee7bde
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_8rj6d0c\cftime_a623918a367c408c9828a26ecbee7bde\src
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_8rj6d0c\cftime_a623918a367c408c9828a26ecbee7bde\src\cftime

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION "-IC
:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0kxsw1of\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" "-Ie:\summer research\include" "-IC:\Use
rs\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include" "-IC:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include" "-I
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program
Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\
Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "/TcC:\Users\User\AppData\Loca
l\Temp\pip-install-_8rj6d0c\cftime_a623918a367c408c9828a26ecbee7bde\src\cftime\_cftime.c" "/Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\Users\User\AppData
\Local\Temp\pip-install-_8rj6d0c\cftime_a623918a367c408c9828a26ecbee7bde\src\cftime\_cftime.obj"
  _cftime.c
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO "/LIBPATH:
e:\summer research\libs" "/LIBPATH:C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\libs" "/LIBPATH:C:\Users\User\AppData\L
ocal\Programs\Python\Python38-32" "/LIBPATH:e:\summer research\PCbuild\win32" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB" "/LI
BPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x86" "/L
IBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x86" /EXPORT:PyInit__cftime "build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\Users\User\AppDat
a\Local\Temp\pip-install-_8rj6d0c\cftime_a623918a367c408c9828a26ecbee7bde\src\cftime\_cftime.obj" /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.8\cftime\_cftime.cp38-win32.pyd
 "/IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_8rj6d0c\cftime_a623918a367c408c9828a26ecbee7bde\src\cftime\
_cftime.cp38-win32.lib"
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_8rj6d0c\cftime_a62391
8a367c408c9828a26ecbee7bde\src\cftime\_cftime.cp38-win32.lib'
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1104
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cftime
Failed to build cftime
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cftime which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I have tried looking at the error on the Microsoft [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1104?view=msvc-160&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019) and so far the possible sources could be:

1. Path length too long --> I don't think it is the path length causing the issue because it doesn't exceed 300 characters
2. Running a 32-bit package on 64-bit Windows --> I tried installing the 64-bit wheel file with pip but it doesn't work. Only the 32-bit wheel package is working but without cftime.

My python version is also correct. Please help if you know how to fix this error. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
C:>pip install netCDF4
```

or

```
C:>pip3 install netCDF4
```

see [netCDF4 documentation here for more details](https://pypi.org/project/netCDF4/)

Comment: I’ve been trying: pip install netcdf4 but it keeps getting stuck on building wheel for the cftime dependency.

Comment: try this: pip install cftime and you can download all dependencies via links mentioned  [here](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/)

Comment: On further digging the issue I found that wheels simply aren't supported with PEP 517 builds. My best guess would be to pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel and that should resolve the issue or use --no-binary, tutorial [here](https://discuss.python.org/t/pep-517-and-projects-that-cant-install-via-wheels/791)

Comment: Ok will try that and let you know. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY SOLVED IT AHHHH!!!!
I downloaded the unofficial windows binaries for cftime from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#cftime) and put it in the same directory as the python38.exe file in my Pycharm project (virtualenv). Then on the terminal I inputted:

```
pip install <path link to cftime .whl >
```

which installed the cftime dependency.

In the terminal I re-tried: `pip install netcdf4` and now it could download the entire package because the cftime problematic dependency was finally installed.